# Application.Exit(): Does it start a new thread (my program continues execution in parallel)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exit

I have a multi-threaded application, and both in the main UI thread and in other background threads, I have stop-methods that call Application.Exit().

The weird thing is that after the call, the program continues on to the next line (and then eventually exits). The obvious problem with this can be explained with the simple code below:

```
if (XYZ) Application.Exit();
Globals.Instance.LoggerDictionary["ApplicationLog"].Log("Bla bla...");
```

And this:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null && string.Equals(button.Name, @"CloseButton"))
        {
            //FormClosing event raised by a user created button action
        }
        else
        {
            //FormClosing event raised by program or the X in top right corner
            Globals.Instance.LoggerDictionary["ApplicationLog"].Dispose();
            Globals.Instance.LoggerDictionary["OtherLog"].Dispose();
            MemoryHandler.Instance.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

As seen the FormClosing method ensures that cleanup of unmanaged resources is done. So, in many cases the application moves on to the line below Application.Exit(), and, in the example above, try to write something to the Log, which has already been disposed by the FormClosing() method.

**My question is therefore:** Does Application.Exit() spawn a new thread where FormClosing() is run from? If not, then why does it continue on?

Comment: You probably find everything explained in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

This method does not terminate the process. Instant termination is rarely a useful shutdown model because it is unclear what useful shutdown actions would be skipped.

If this method does not terminate the process then clearly your code must continue to run.

This is normal and the right way to shut down the app. If you want to skip certain logic, set a flag `bool isShuttingDown` and react to it.

Comment: usr, should it not wait until the message pumps have terminated, before it moves to the next line? What you are saying is that the closing of these message pumps happens on a new thread? If not, the app should not be able to continue on before done with that work.

Comment: The message pumps can only shut down (in a reasonable way) once all messages have been drained. It is not a good idea to just halt processing and leave all UI resource hanging unresponsively. Exit instructs all windows to close. None of this work happens on a new thread. The shutdown request is just being registered and then executed cooperatively.

Comment: @Magnus The order is like this: You call `Exit()`, inside that function it calls any registered closing events, it then returns to the caller and waits for the caller to return to the message pump, it then processes the remaining messages in the pump, once the pump is empty it then stops the application.

Comment: I guess I do not completely understand who/what shuts down my application, if not the application itself? If I shut myself down, then i should not be able to move to next line before being done with shutting down (and at that point obviously cannot move to next line).

Comment: @Magnus Imagine that `Application.Exit()` does a `BeginInvoke(() => Environment.Exit(0))` inside of it. So the real exit does not happen until control is returned to the message pump and all the pending messages are processed. This is not what really happens but it is pretty close to it. The next line of your example gets run because "Enviorment.Exit" does not run till after your function executes the rest of its code and returns to the message pump.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think you know this but to clarify: `App.Exit` makes `App.Run` return. It never kills the process. It does not even influence non-UI threads.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Last question here guys: Is every method that is called in my program added to this so called message queue that the message loop handles? If so, it makes sense why the method must complete before exit happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Magnus No (for your specific case) only "[Windows Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590(v=vs.85).aspx)" are put in the message queue which are exposed in .NET as the events in classes derived from `Control` (Click, Paint, Resize, ect) or things you explicitly put on the queue by doing `Control.BeginInvoke`. Your function that calls `Application.Exit()` most likely is called from one of those events (likely a ButtonClick event), so you are inside the message loop while you are running your code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, so essentially every method in a WinForm application is in the Message Queue then, as everything, one way or another, comes from an event raised by a Control (even the running of the MainForm() constructor is in the loop: "Application.Run(new MainForm());" <--- the MainForm is here put in the message queue right?

Comment: @Magnus every method running on the UI thread is being called (indirectly) from the message loop. Once the loop stops nothing runs on the UI thread anymore and App.Run returns.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry for all the questions, but hope this is the last one here: Is this correct: 1) An event happens in a window in the application. 2) The application adds the event (all derived methods) to the message queue. 3) The OS reads the message queue through GetMessage() or PeekMessage() in order to react to the event. --- I'm just trying to understand the point of the Message Loop (I read it is for communication with other processes, in this case the OS i guess)

Comment: @usr Not just on the UI thread though, also on threads spawned by the UI thread, right?

Comment: @Magnus you have some ideas about how this works that are magic. I'll simplify a bit: The UI thread is essentially: `while(true) { ExecuteMessage(GetMessage()); }`. All it does is call your click handler. At this point the UI framework is no longer in the game. Your code runs and does whatever it wants. The UI framework does not need to know what you're doing. It couldn't care less about the call tree. Explain, why it would need to care. It also does not track spawned threads (and there is no facility in .NET to even do that). The message loop has nothing to do with inter-process communication

Comment: Ahhh, wow, sorry for being so slow, I had misunderstood some basic concepts. The whole reason the UI thread is alive IS the message loop. Once the message loop is done, Application.Run() returns, and the application shuts down. But lets say we have a button that spawns a new thread, and in that thread a method StopApp() { Application.Exit(); Console.WriteLine("HERE"); } resides. The message loop should not wait for StopApp() to return, because the button event method has already returned. So "HERE" should not be printed...

Comment: @Magnus "should"? Does that mean "I think it does not" or "I want it to be so"? Cancellation is cooperative in .NET. You *must* arrange yourself for your own threads to end. Exit just signals the loop to end at its convenience later. (Don't apologize, you're getting this. I only invest that much commentary into worthy learners.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! With "should", I meant: I have observed that "HERE" was in fact printed, when conceptually I did not think it should be. With your new comment I am getting why it might be still printed though. Is the following correct? If StopApp() resided in a Button_Clicked event method in the UI thread, "HERE" would always be printed because the message loop actually waits for Button_Clicked to return before exiting. If it instead resided in a thread I spawned myself, it is not guaranteed to be printed, as the message loop is not waiting for StopApp() to return. To be continued:

Comment: ... In the latter case it will most likely still be printed however, because it takes some time for the message loop to empty and FormClosing / Disposing to happen.

Comment: If PRINT is in the click handler it will run as you said. If it is on a custom thread, why would it not run? Can you detail any scenario in which it would not run?

Comment: It would not run if the message loop is already empty and the FormClosing/cleanup events done by Application.Exit() goes by incredibly fast, so the custom thread does not have time to make it to the next line. It is probably very hypothetical, but the point I am trying to make is that we are not forced to wait for this method in the custom thread to return, because it is not in the message loop (while the StopApp() in the UI thread would be in the message loop).

Comment: A better example is if you put a Thread.Sleep(5000); between Application.Exit(); and Console.WriteLine("HERE");. In the case of the StopApp() in the UI thread, the "HERE" would print as the method is in the message loop. If it is on a custom thread, it was my impression that it would not be in the message loop, so it does not wait for StopApp() to return before shutting down.

Comment: Custom threads are not shut down when the UI shuts down. The UI doesn't know about them in any way.

Comment: If it is a background thread it will terminate when the foreground thread (UI thread) terminates, no?

Comment: Background threads are terminated when all foreground threads have terminated. The background thread property has nothing to do with UI frameworks. The two don't interact in any way.

Comment: So in other words, if I put a Thread.Sleep(10000) between the Exit() and the PRINT, the print will most likely not happen (in the case that StopApp() is on another thread). Reason: The foreground thread's message loop will not wait for StopApp() to return, and once the foreground thread shuts down it will pull the background thread with it (which is now waiting at Thread.Sleep(10000). Agreed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have set Thread.IsBackground to true. But, this shutdown model is not recommended as it results in a rude abort using TAE. A cooperative shutdown model is better.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not start a new thread.  It also doesn't immediately kill the UI thread.  The whole point of `Application.Exit` is to gracefully exit the application.  All forms will be asked to be closed, resources will be cleaned up, all pumped through the main application loop.  When the application loop next becomes idle, rather than waiting for more messages, it will instead stop pumping messages and the application will continue running after the call to `Appliaction.Run` that created the message loop in the first place.  That thread can then go on to do whatever (usually end; unless you've added more code).

Comment: I added some comments to the other answers. It is possible that I do not understand this message pump/loop concept. I am trying to read up on it now.

Comment: Servy, I did not at first understand your message, but now I get what you are saying and see why it makes sense. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not spawn a extra thread. Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/a.html#de629df25701f0c2) inside the function it will call each form's FormClosing event, it then returns control to the caller. Once the caller completes and control returns to the message loop that is when the program will actually shut down.

All of this happens on the single UI thread.

Comment: Ugh..it still does not make sense to me why it moves on to the next line after Application.Exit(). If it is on one thread, then it should not be able to move to the next line until FormClosing is complete (where disposing and such is done). And if FormClosing is done, does it not immediately shut down? Or is there a lag there where another thread tries to shut the app down (therefore allowing the app to continue to next line)? Thanks so much!

Comment: It does not immediately shut down. Application.Exit() returns, it lets the method finish, then when your method returns to the message pump that is when it shuts down (if there are no outstanding messages waiting to be processed)

Comment: Ah, i see! So i need a "return;" after every Application.Exit();. I am trying to read up on this message pump/loop concept now. It seems to be important to grasp.